# Java unable to read signed negative bytes written to standard out

Tags: java, powershell, pipe, byte

I have 2 classes, the first is fed a binary string of 1s and 0s to standard in, and splits the string into sub strings of length 8 to convert to bytes, to write to standard out like so:

```
byte b = (byte)Integer.parseInt(byteString, 2);
System.out.write(b);
System.out.flush();
```

The second is piped the output of the first, and ultimately will turn the bytes back into the long binary string, but currently I have it just doing this:

```
int next;
    while((next = System.in.read())!=-1){
    System.out.print(next); System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.flush();
}
```

If I replace `System.out.write(b);` with `System.out.print(b); System.out.print(" ");` in the first class with some small sample input, the output is `-80 -84 83 11 98 -116 53 -119 49 27 10 -80 -72 104 -123 0`

If I pipe this output to the second class it outputs `63 63 83 11 98 63 53 63 49 27 13 10 63 63 104 63 0 13 10`

Two things seem to be happening that I can't figure out why, `System.in.read()` is returning `63`, which is ASCII for `?` when reading bytes that would be signed negative, and a carriage return + new line has been added to the end. I am stumped for solutions, insight is greatly appreciated.

Note: I was running this in Windows 10 powershell, but on normal command line and in a linux terminal the behaviour was as expected, so problem is only in powershell!

Comment: Java `System.in.read()` reads raw binary.  Bytes, not ASCII strings, which is what you are printing.  Try wrapping System.in in a Reader of some sort.

Comment: I was running this in Windows 10 powershell, but on normal command line and in a linux terminal the behaviour was as expected, so problem is only in powershell but still not sure why

Comment: @ogilberry this information should be part of the question and not just a comment... maybe addind the powershell tag also helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not use powershell, but a small test shows that pipes do change the output, like adding a newline and carriage return at the end, or converting the byte 0xA2 to 0x3f ('?').

Searching the net I found [Understanding the Windows PowerShell Pipeline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/fundamental/understanding-the-windows-powershell-pipeline). I did not read more than the first paragraph, but that contains a hint:

> Piping works virtually everywhere in Windows PowerShell. Although you see text on the screen, Windows PowerShell **does not pipe text between commands. Instead, it pipes objects.**

Maybe this helps: [What exactly does the pipe | mean in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028439/what-exactly-does-the-pipe-mean-in-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

```
int next;
while((next = System.in.read())!=-1){
    System.out.print(next); System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.flush();
}
```

Bytes are signed in Java, and so is the result of `InputStream.read()`. Try this:

```
int next;
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(System.in);
for (;;)
{
    try
    {
        next = in.readUnsignedByte();
        System.out.print(next); System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.flush();
    }
    catch (EOFException exc)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the result of  `InputStream.read()` is an `int` and always non-negative or -1 (EOF), javadoc: "...The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255... ", the question is not showing any negative number being read ("63 63 83 11 98 63 53 63 49 27 13 10 63 63 104 63 0 13 10"), and it is working on normal command line or linux shell, just not in a powershell (see question comments) - and above code should give same result as question's one... (it is `read(byte[])` that can/will return negative bytes)

Comment: just tested your code, **it is** having the same behavior as question ones!