# Compressing to tar.xz using 7-zip through a pipe on windows

Tags: powershell, pipe, 7zip

My command line is this (powershell):

```
$7z ="`"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe`""
&$7z a -r -ttar -bd -so . | &$7z a -r -txz -bd $archive -si
```

The produced archive file indeed contains a tar file, but that tar file is corrupt.

Note, that breaking the pipe into two commands works correctly:

```
&$7z a -r -ttar -bd ${archive}.tmp .
&$7z a -r -txz -bd $archive ${archive}.tmp
```

The produced archive is perfectly valid.

So, what is wrong with my pipeline?

(I am using Powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `| %{ "$_" }` in between the pipes like

```
&$7z a -r -ttar -bd -so . | %{ "$_" } | &$7z a -r -txz -bd $archive -si
```

The point is that the second call to `7z` expects unmodified data on *STDIN*, but PowerShell is converting the output from the first call to `7z` to (multiple) (string) objects. `%` is an alias for `foreach-object`, so what the additional command does is to loop over each object and convert it to a plain string before passing it on to the second call to `7z`.

*Edit:* Reading through [PowerShell’s Object Pipeline Corrupts Piped Binary Data](http://brianreiter.org/2010/01/29/powershells-object-pipeline-corrupts-piped-binary-data/) it looks to me now as if my suggestion would not work, and there's also no way to fix it. Well, other than wrapping the whole pipeline into a `cmd /c "..."` call to make `cmd` and not PowerShell handle the pipeline.

*Edit2:* I also was trying [this solution](http://www.powershellcookbook.com/recipe/WCiL/capture-and-redirect-binary-process-output) from the PowerShell Cookbook, but it was very slow.

In the end, I created a `.cmd` script with the `7z` pipes that I'm calling from my PowerShell script.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. What a blunder from the PowerShell part.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing is wrong with your pipeline it is the way that the pipeline works that's causing the error.

`PowerShell` pipe works in an asynchronous way. Meaning that output of the first command is available to the second command immediately one object at the time even if the first one has not finished executing, [See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324392/how-does-the-powershell-pipeline-concept-work)

Both `Unix` and `PowerShell` pipes operate in the same way. The reason why you might be seeing a difference from `Unix` to `PowerShell` is the way in which they go about it is different.

`Unix` passes `Strings` between the commands. Where as a `Powershell` pipe will pass `full-fledged .net object` between commands. This difference in the data type being past between command will be why it works on `unix` and not in `PowerShell`. If `7z.exe` can not huddle these `.net objects` correctly the files will be come corrupt, [See here](https://superuser.com/questions/223300/powershell-vs-the-unix-shell).

Comment: I do not see why this should be a problem. Isn't it how pipes work in unix as well? And yet `tar cf - A | gzip -9 > B.tar.gz` is perfectly valid there. And as far as I know the content becomes available on the pipe as soon as it is produced and continues to flow on the pipe until the pipe is closed by the source.

Comment: So all is lost? Or is there a way to make the pipe work with 7-zip in Powershell after all?

Comment: @mark It does make a difference because `7z`, not being a PowerShell command, expects plain data on *STDIN* and not .NET objects. See my answer for a possible solution.