# Why does powershell loop more times than I expect?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to change the names of 561 images using powershell. The first and second changes met my expectations, but when I tried to undo the second change a third time, the results did not meet my expectations.

here is my code:

```bash
PS E:\PART_5> $a = 1
PS E:\PART_5> Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {
>> $name = "newName_$a" + $_.Extension
>> Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $name
>> $a = $a + 1
>> }

PS E:\PART_5> $a = 1
PS E:\PART_5> Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {
>> $name = "newestName_$a" + $_.Extension
>> Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $name
>> $a = $a + 1
>> }

PS E:\PART_5> $a = 1
PS E:\PART_5> Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {
>> $name = "newName_$a" + $_.Extension
>> Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $name
>> $a = $a + 1
>> }
```

and results:

| First execution result | Second execution result | Third execution result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| newName_1.jpg | newestName_1.jpg | newName_1000.jpg |
| newName_2.jpg | newestName_2.jpg | newName_1001.jpg |
| ... | ... | ... |
| newName_561.jpg | newestName_561.jpg | newName_1560.jpg |

To test I output the variable "a" in the process and the most amazing thing happened.

```bash
PS E:\PART_5> $a = 1
PS E:\PART_5> Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {
>> $name = "newestName_$a" + $_.Extension
>> Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $name
>> $a
>> $a = $a + 1
>> }

PS E:\PART_5> $a = 1
PS E:\PART_5> Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {
>> $name = "newName_$a" + $_.Extension
>> Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $name
>> $a
>> $a = $a + 1
>> }
```

When I loop through these two pieces of code, I find that "newestName" is always correct, looping  "a" from 1 to 561; and "newName" is always wrong, and looping from 1 to 1560.

[image]

I don't know what the problem is and I hope someone can tell me.

Comment: And you're 100% sure you didn't accidentally set `$a = 1000` before the third loop? It's also quite strange that you have 561 files during the first 4 attempts and then suddenly 1561 files in the last attempt... Can you do `Get-ChildItem E:\PART_5 |Measure` to test how many files/subfolders you actually have in the directory?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Of course, I'm sure there's nothing wrong

Comment: I've actually done this and there are indeed only 561 files. And I have used "-Verbose" in "Rename-Item". I found that after completing the loop, "ForEach-Object" continued to loop, accumulating the variable "a" and renaming the file from the beginning. This is really weird, but it happened on my computer to the point where I started to wonder what was wrong with my computer. @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: Since you are note using any filter on Get-ChildItem, files that already have been renamed can be picked up again and again and again.. Either capture the result of Get-ChildItem in a variable first and then loop over that OR enclose the cmd in between brackets `(Get-ChildItem)` so the command will finish collecting file and foldernames before it enters the loop.

Comment: Thanks, I seem to understand. I used to think that the command connected by the pipeline will start the next command after the execution of the previous one is completed, but in fact, it does not wait for the previous command to complete, and the next command will start executing when it has output. Can I understand it this way?

Comment: @并鱼厥切 No, the pipeline goes back and forth one item at a time.

Comment: OK,I will find some information to study.

Comment: @并鱼厥切, "Can I understand it this way?", I would say essentially yes.  The "No" that js2010 answered is that they do not run on parallel threads, or at the same time.  Your pipeline has 2 stages, I will call them s1 and s2.  First s1 gets a file and puts on the pipeline, s2 receives the file from the pipeline and renames it, s1 gets another file and puts on the pipeline, etc.  When I first learned about the pipeline, I thought s2 would process items received from s1 on another thread, but it is still the same thread, just taking turns doing s1, then s2, s1, s2, s1, s2, s1, etc...

Comment: @并鱼厥切, if the next command waited for the previous command to complete, there would be no advantage in using a pipeline.  In some cases, pipeline blocking must occur. A sort cannot output any data until it has received and processed the last item. That is becase the last item it receives may be the item that must go out first.

Comment: @并鱼厥切, take a look at [Keith Hill's excellent example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17329863/4190564).